# Why am I unable to NOT use timestamps in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these:

posts table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 64);
            $table->string('teaser', 128)->nullable();
            $table->text('content', 50000);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

posts model

```
use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'teaser', 'content'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
```

tag table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('text', 32);
        });
    }
```

tag model

```
use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $fillable = ['text'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_tag', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
```

post_tag table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
        });
    }
```

When I try to create a new post with tags, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'test' for column `laravel`.`post_tag`.`tag_id` at row 1
INSERT INTO
  `post_tag` (`post_id`, `tag_id`)
VALUES
  (31, test)
```

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
public function store(PostFormValidation $request)
    {
        $newpost = Post::create($request->validated());
        $newpost->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }
```

But why is it complaining about the timestamps, when I removed them from the migration and specified that I'm not using any in the model too? What am I missing?

The submitted "tags" is a multiple select.

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code, just post the code :)

Comment: I'll update in a second, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: No worries, its a rookie mistake :) But yeah, 'test' is not an ID(numeric) so that's your problem :)

Comment: Can you share how `$request->tags` looks like in `$newpost->tags()->sync($request->tags);`. Just add it to the question please ;)

Comment: I added an answer leading you to the docs and doc examples ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is in:

```
$newpost->tags()->sync($request->tags);
```

I would recommend looking at [this laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) to see that the format should be:

```
$newpost->tags()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

Or:

```
$newpost->tags()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

Comment: the problem is, when you pass a tag that does not exist in the "Tags" table yet, it tries to register its text instead. So if you have this in the database: ``` 0|test, 1|asd, 2|abc``` and you add a new select option called "foobar", it wont have an ID since it's not in the database.

I thought using sync inserts the not existing records into the table, so I'll need to figure out how to do so :D and then attach it back to the post save method so it can sync the newly inserted values.

Comment: I think the main problem is you are trying to skip a step ;) You need to create the tag before linking it. You could check if tag exist, and create if not. If you want, I can update my answer to include that

Comment: Honestly, I'm beginning to lose faith in my "not so coding career". I'm was trying to get a job, I've got to do a test which they said it was fine  but I needed to practice more. They insist I must use laravel and select2 to dynamically create tags (with select2 tagging), but I just can't figure out how to do it "well", following everything they need (like SOLID, Eloquent, etc). I've been struggling with this for actual months now and I can't proceed. I can't believe I'm saying this but I'm about to have a breakdown over this. I'm losing will to continue even tho I took 1-2 week breaks

Comment: Well, programming is a steep learning curve, depending where you come from ofc. I started learning it at 14, am 34 now and still learning. It's a creative job but even creative jobs can get repetitive :P I think the assignment makes sense. You just have to do a step by step analisys of what needs to happen and in wat order. Could you add the `$request->tags` output to your question? Then I will do my best to help you out ;) Oh, and breath in and breath out to prevent/help with anxiety ;)

Comment: Oh, and if you could share the tags table layout(which fields are unique),  that would help as well

Comment: $request->tags ---> it returns either "null" (if no tags were selected) or an array like this: ```array:2 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\PostController.php:42
  0 => "test"
  1 => "izouliépoulizkujtz"
]```

Comment: Allright, and in your tags table, is the name of the tag set to unique(i think it should be)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250965/discussion-between-techno-and-adhdisdev).

Answer (score 1):

You tyining instert in field tag_id 'test' word, but tag_id `unsignedbiginteger`